# Search api solr - index based on field rather than entity

Tags: search, plugins

I have a custom field that has 3 columns and I'm trying to create search page (search_api, solr and view based on search api index to display data) that will perform a search on this field (attached to a node). It kinda works but I'm getting all results grouped per node whereas I need to group results per field. That's if there are 4 results in a given node, it will return that node 4 times. It's actually the same behavior views provide on content based displays: "Display all values in the same row" but this option is disabled for index based displays.

I was trying 3 different approaches non of which I had success with:

1. Create custom Datasource plugin - I can't find any useful examples or documentation and it seems to be the problem to build Datasource on something that's not Entity.
2. Create SearchApiProcessor - again, no relevant examples on what I'm looking for but there seem to be assumption that there is only one value per entity in:

   addFieldValues(ItemInterface $item);
3. I was trying to alter the query via `search_api_solr_query_alter` but again no success.

From what I've found so far it looks like the only way will be to replace the field by custom entity and re-import data but I'd rather go the Datasource plugin route of at all possible.

Could anybody please point me the right direction? What appeared a common use case turns out to be rather impossible.
Thanks